# How to make a div not get below the other div's when zooming in

Tags: html, css-position

I have searched without any answers. I know I should do something like

```
<div class="menu_wrapper">
 <div class="menu_box_item"></div>  <div class="menu_box_item"></div> 
</div>
```

When zooming in the div's appear under each other. I have tried using `position:relative;` in the wrapper and position absolute in the menu_box items.

Comment: What is the CSS applied to the div's? Do you mean zooming in as in increasing the font size, or zooming in as in increasing the page size (as many modern browsers are doing nowadays).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div's appear under each other because they are block elements. If you want them side by side change class to this:

```
.menu_box_item {float: left; width: 50%;}
```

You can also try to add this under your item classes:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but you probably want:

```
div.menu_box_item
{
    display: inline; /* this line is only needed for some old browsers */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Also, it looks like you're creating a list of links across the top of the page? You should be using `<ul>` and `<li>` tags for that. For example:

```
<ul id="nav_menu">
  <li><a href="foo">Foo</a></li>
  <li><a href="bar">Bar</a></li>
</ul>

ul#nav_menu
{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul#nav_menu li
{
  display: inline; /* this line is only needed for some old browsers */
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px; /* minimum width of your nav items */
}
```